# How to handle render method until redux has returned results?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, state

I am creating a component that fetches some apis to populate result.There are some transformations needed on those api results before rendering. I've used `componentWillMount` method to set redux state. I need to handle `render` method until redux those results to props. This takes some time. Since data is not available, render method will fail at that moment. I've tried setting `default state` but that doesn't seem to work since `redux state` will be mapped to props with `mapStateToProps` method. What is the correct and efficient approach to handle such case??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Normally you will render a different thing (or you won't render at all) when your data is not present.

```
{this.props.unreadMessages.length > 0 &&
    <h2>
      You have {this.props.unreadMessages.length} unread messages.
    </h2>
}
```

or:

```
if (this.props.unreadMessages.length > 0) {
  return <Main unreadMessages={this.props.unreadMessages} />;
} else {
  return <Loading />
}
```

You can also have your default initial state and render based on that when `props` does not have data. maybe with something like:

```
<h2>
 Hello, {this.props.username || this.state.username}.
</h2>
```

Also, the recommended lifecycle hook for Ajax call is `componentDidMount`.

Answer (score 0):

If your data is not ready, you can use conditional rendering. Add additional indicator about your data, Like this

```
 render() { 
    if (!this.props.data) { 
       return null;
    }
    return <YourComponent />;
}
```

And you'd better to fetch data in `componentDidMount` lifecycle.

Answer (score 0):

I would check for the props in the render method with a ternary expression as a sort of guard clause. Something like this, for example:

```
render(){
    return (<React.Fragment>
    { this.props.user ? <IntendedComponent ...this.props.user /> : <Loading user={defaultUser}/> }
    <React.Fragment/>);
}
```

If the user prop has not been populated yet, it should be empty and display an alternate component (like the loading component in the example) or the intended component with default, hardcoded values. Once the data is in place, you can pass the data to a component  as you see fit.

Answer (score 0):

First of all componentWillMount is not a good method to call apis,
as per react documentation:

> componentDidMount() is invoked immediately after a component is
>   mounted (inserted into the tree). Initialization that requires DOM
>   nodes should go here. If you need to load data from a remote endpoint,
>   this is a good place to instantiate the network request.
>
> This method is a good place to set up any subscriptions. If you do
>   that, don’t forget to unsubscribe in componentWillUnmount().

Here is the link: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount

Here is what you can do till data is loaded:
get one flag into redux state called `dataLoaded:false`
Once the data is loaded you performed an operations you can easily change it.

And in `render()`

```
if(this.props.dataLoaded){
  <loadingComponent></loadingComponent>
} else {
  //operation is performed
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using `Redux`, you can set the default `Redux state` in `Reducers` using ES6 default parameters. Something like this:

```
const apiStatus = (state='fetching', action) => {
   // handle dispatch action
}
```

And in React, you can use [Conditional Rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html) to `render` a loading icon, for instance, while state is `fetching`. Then when state is `finished`, take the result and `render` the real elements.

To work with Async in Redux, see this link: 
[Async Action](https://redux.js.org/advanced/async-actions)